# When do I have to 'require' a Ruby class in my Rake task?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm working on a Rake task which fetches a file via an external URL. To do this, I have to require the [Net::HTTP](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html) Ruby class in my .rake file.

This seems odd to me, because I've not loaded it in as a gem (I've not downloaded it from anywhere in fact), so this Ruby class must be pre-installed in the Rails framework. Yet in every .rake file I have, I have to `require` it. So it must, for some reason, be inactive until I tell it otherwise(?).

This is **not** the same question as ["How to require classes that *I've* created in different files"](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/auto-load). Rather, I want to know

- How it is that I don't have to download and install the Net::HTTP class into my application?
- Why do I have to manually require it when I use it, if it's already  pre-installed in Rails?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Net::HTTP is part of the [Ruby Standard Library](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.3/), which is distributed with Ruby itself (not Rails).  To use any of the standard libraries you must require them first.

Comment: So anything that is built in modern Ruby can utilize these libraries, but must `require` them manually. Correct?

Answer (score -2):

> I'm working on a Rake task which fetches a file via an external URL. To do this, I have to require the [Net::HTTP](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Net/HTTP.html) Ruby class in my .rake file.

No, you don't. You don't `require` classes, ever. `require` loads files, not classes.

> This seems odd to me, because I've not loaded it in as a gem (I've not downloaded it from anywhere in fact), so this Ruby class must be pre-installed in the Rails framework.

No, it isn't. It is a part of the Ruby standard library. You even linked to the documentation of the Ruby standard library!

> Yet in every .rake file I have, I have to `require` it. So it must, for some reason, be inactive until I tell it otherwise(?).

Yes. Ruby doesn't magically `require` every Ruby file in the entire world. You have to `require` the files you need manually and explicitly.

> - How it is that I don't have to download and install the Net::HTTP class into my application?

Because the `Net::HTTP` class is defined inside the file `net/http.rb`, which is shipped as part of the Ruby standard library.

> - Why do I have to manually require it when I use it, if it's already  pre-installed in Rails?

Because it's a Ruby file like any other Ruby file, and you need to tell Ruby which Ruby files you want to use.

Comment: While reading this, I felt like you were yelling at me, and you were very frustrated with someone like myself, who isn't super experienced in Rails. Please try to be kind, and patient with those of us who are just getting on our feet.

Comment: This way of talking down to people is problematic. These people state their understanding of a system as though it is immutable and universal law which everyone should know. It's super unhelpful.